# Is java reliable on precise timing code?

Tags: java, performance, timer

I know c and c++ but i am more comfortable with java.
I am willing to experiment in some brain computer interface. In order to try out the subliminal option I require that the program will be able to execute code with good time precision. down to the milliseconds.

My question is, can I rely on java or should I go for c++ or c#?

Comment: Define "good time precision". Are you requiring soft or hard realtime? Some of this might also affect your choice of OS, not only language.

Comment: Take a look at Real Time Java (http://www.rtsj.org). Perhaps someone else can give more detailed information about its stability.

Comment: I remember Sun was really into getting the JVM to be thought of as a real time environment back in 2004-2006 (http://youtu.be/lXct7Bzdhzw). I haven't heard much about it since then.

Comment: There is no chance for us to know if one or the other system matches your unspecific specifications. What does "time precision" mean for you?

Comment: oracle's rtsj is pretty much dead, maybe you'll have some luck with IBM's.. in any case, you should define "precise timing" very carefully before choosing a language (and an architecture)

Answer (score 1):

if you use the vm argument `-server`, java is faster on some executions than gcc.

```
java -jar -server myJar.har
```

Answer (score 0):

In brief: No. Not least because Java, being a garbage-collected language, may take time out at any moment to pick up its scattered marbles.

Java is good for many things. Realtime is not one of them. Try C or assembler.

Comment: Not true, java can be great for real time applications like 3D games. There are 3d libraries available with full OpenGL binding and modern java with a not idiotically written program won't experience noticeable gc pauses due to concurrent garbage collection. However it is less good at extreme precision timings. A human would never notice though. I'm not sure about *this* task but don't write java off for all real time

Comment: @RichardTingle: An interface requiring millisecond-level precision, though, would almost definitely notice.

Comment: @cHao I'm not actually sure about that. It may be true but my total tick is 17ms (running at 60fps) and it does *a lot* in that tick; including passing 16 tasks to threads. Microsecond would probably not be great but milliseconds is probably ok. Probably worth some testing but I'm on mobile at the moment

Comment: Java can _perform_ very well. Very predictably... having done deep peformance analysis of large Java applications, I'm not convinced. Very precisely... hard to say without predictability.

Comment: @RichardTingle: Thing is, though, if you run into GC pauses and can't finish everything you need to do in that 17ms, that's OK (if suboptimal); things just get jittery and such.  For true real-time purposes, though, that code would be considered broken, as the performance isn't predictable anymore.

Comment: @cHao While that can happen it happens (in my experience) from physically trying to stuff too much into a tick (usually graphics rebuilds for me) rather than anything timing related. And that would be the same in any language. The question is whether a system under moderate load would ever "oversleep" and miss its wake up call by a noticeable margin (where a noticeable margin might be 1 millisecond). However;  if people die if there is a gc pause then I take your point

Comment: @cHao: For a crazy low latency system processing 6M orders per second see [LMAX](http://martinfowler.com/articles/lmax.html).

Comment: @maaartinus: I know Java can be fast.  But "fast" != "realtime". A realtime system doesn't even have to be fast. What it does need is a certain *guaranteed* level of performance.  Even at 6M orders/sec, an extra few microseconds processing one order won't break stuff; the system is fast enough to clear out any resulting backlog quickly.  But what if the nature of the data is such that there can't *be* a backlog?  Failure to meet a deadline can mean data going missing or getting corrupted. That's realtime. And Java fails by default, partly because GC pauses can happen whenever.

Comment: @cHao: I agree, but IIRC LMAX *has* some real-time guarantees.  I can't find it anymore, nor I recall what was the maximum allowed latency or if / how often they were allowed to miss the deadline. So let's forget it, the GC simply is a big problem.